# Payload to CSV Using Data weave- Issue with CSV cell format

Tags: csv, format, mule, dataweave

FixedLengthFlat File to CSV conversion

Am trying to convert input payload `List<List<String>>` to CSV using Data weave in Mule. Followed by a File connector to create a CSV file externally.

Following is the Data weave script

```
%dw 1.0
 %output application/csv separator=","
 ---
 payload map 
 {
 cNmbr:$[0] ++ " " as :string,
 "pNmbr":$[1] as  :number,
 "sId":$[2] as :number,
 "sCode":$[3],
 "termDate":$[4],
 "termCode":$[5] as :number,
 "termRsn":$[6]
 }
```

The file is success fully getting created with same values as am passing from input. **EX: 100000000019,000000000000000006,767698780,CR,20170520,006,Non Payment**

Problem here is, CSV file is getting created successfully from mule but when I try to open CSV file, the data values are seen as **1E+11,9,767698777,CR,20170517 6,Non Payment**

Same is seen good when in notepad++.

How can I handle this format issue when we open it in CSV file format??

Comment: Is the way csv file format. You need to format itl. Refer:https://superuser.com/questions/861964/how-do-i-stop-excel-from-converting-value-0503e000-to-5-03e02-automatically

Comment: Also refer: http://businessintelligence.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/cognos8-l/data-formatting-in-cognos-reports-while-exported-to-csv-4891149